# Apache Redirect domain.com/dir/slug to sub.domain.com/dir/slug silently without .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, subdirectory

I'm having the darndest time trying to figure this out.

I have a site on a legacy system which will not permit me to alter the .htaccess file at domain.com. I have moved part of this site to a WordPress install located at sub.domain.com. I have to make the URL domain.com/dir/ redirect silently to sub.domain.com/dir/. How can I go about this? I can edit the Apache config files for both domain.com and sub.domain.com, and the .htaccess for sub.domain.com, but not the .htaccess for domain.com

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just add the redirect into the apache config files. In the virtualhost for domain.com:

```
Redirect 301 / http://sub.domain.com/
```

If by "silently" (not sure what that's supposed to mean since redirects are involve the browser sending a new request), I'm guessing you want to reverse proxy? Then you'd need to make sure mod_proxy is loaded, then do:

```
ProxyPass / http://sub.domain.com/
```